# MySQL database sorting

Tags: mysql, sql

```
show tables from questiontables
where Tables_in_questiontables like '%1235504788%'
ORDER BY Tables_in_questiontables desc limit 1;
```

questiontables is database name,
my qus. is where is the error in my syntax?

Comment: SHOW is not an ANSI SQL statement. Seems you want a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

[SHOW TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html) statement does not support `order by`, nor `limit` clauses. These are your syntax errors.

Consider using [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html) table with a `select` statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

You want a SQL query.  Assuming that `questiontables` is a schema in your database:

```
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'questiontables' and
      table_name like '%1235504788%'
order by table_name desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
       table_name
FROM 
       information_schema.tables
WHERE 
       table_name LIKE '%1235504788%'

ORDER BY 
       table_name DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Read more about `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html)